# Why is my curl command working and not my python code?

Tags: python, http, curl

I have a curl command that works perfectly fine

```
curl -X POST "https://api.optconnect.com/summit/beta/accounts/login/app_secret" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "content-type: application/json" -d "{  \"accountId\": 000,  \"applicationId\": 000,  \"secret\": \"000\"}"
```

but my python code gives me a bad request error

```
import urllib2
import json

url = 'https://api.optconnect.com/summit/beta/accounts/login/app_secret'

data = {'accountId': '000',
    'applicationId': '000',
    'secret': '000'}
data =json.dumps(data)

headers = {'accept': 'application/json', 'content-type': 'application/json' }


requestt = urllib2.Request(url, data ,headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(requestt)
result = response.read()
print(result)
```

> File "testing.py", line 19, in 
>       response = urllib2.urlopen(requestt)
>     File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
>       return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
>     File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 437, in open
>       response = meth(req, response)
>     File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 550, in http_response
>       'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
>     File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 475, in error
>       return self._call_chain(*args)
>     File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
>       result = func(*args)
>     File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 558, in http_error_default
>       raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
>   urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `curl` JSON, the values of `accountId` and `applicationId` are integers, not strings. That might make a difference to the application. So use:

```
data = {'accountId': 0,
        'applicationId': 0,
        'secret': '000'}
```

Comment: oh gee, that was lame of me. Thanks!

Comment: Why are people downvoting this? It may or may not be the OP's problem, but it's certainly true, and something the OP is doing wrong, and something that could easily cause the OP's problem, and the answer explains everything it needs to.

Comment: @rose Incorrectly natively parsing two layers of quoting in code that you've been staring at all day isn't really "lame" so much as "human"…

Comment: @abarnert They're probably downvoting the answer because they downvoted the question. Some people think that it's wrong to answer bad questions, so they try to punish me for it. I have so much rep that I laugh at their attempts. :)

Comment: @Barmar Sure, I've gotten some punishment downvotes like that, and I don't care about rep either—but I do still like to learn about how to make answers better. I mean, I probably would have written this as 40 lines of details nobody cares about, and I think yours is better than that…

Comment: @abarnert I wish people would explain their DVs, too. That's life in SO.

Comment: Okay, I'll explain my DV. I think this question is poor, and is little better than a typographical error. What I would _wish_ had been done, is that the problem pointed out in the comments, and the question closed as a typographical error. I am not against answers in general, but I am against answers that answer questions that shouldn't be answered in the first place. And if your argument is that this question _is_ useful/helpful, then chances are it has been asked before, why isn't it closed as duplicate then? Either way, this question shouldn't have been answered.

Comment: Nothing personal against you or the OP, just exercising my right to downvote. Also, I'd like to point out in response to "I have so much rep that I laugh at their attempts. :)" that a lot of your answers are to questions of this nature... "high rep" is not much more than an indicator of your participation ;) Look at me for instance.